# Reversing the elements in a 3X3 Array using ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to flip an image and my approach is to reverse the elements in a 3X3 Matrix row by row. I am using a static array called **matrix**.

After I've inserted the values in the 3 by 3 array, I'm iterating through all the rows of the array and storing the values in an ArrayList. Next I'm swapping the elements in that list in a separate function and trying to insert the swapped values in the original array in the function(given the array is static). When I am trying to do that I am getting an index out of bound exception. I tried everything from my end, but this problem seems not be going away. Here's my code :

I've put the print statements to check the size of the list passed, received and after swapping.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlipAndInvert {

    static int rows = 0;
    static int columns = 0;
    static int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the dimensions of the array : ");

        System.out.println("Enter # of Rows  : ");
        rows = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter # of Columns  : ");
        columns = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

                System.out.print("Enter [" + i + "][" + j + "] : ");
                int data = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                if (data == 0 || data == 1) {
                    matrix[i][j] = data;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter Binary Format");
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> store = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                store.add(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("List Size Passed : " + store.size());

            swap(store, i);

        }

    }

    public static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> list, int r) {

        int i = 0;
        int j = list.size() - 1;

        System.out.println("List Size Received : " + list.size());

        if (list.size() % 2 == 1) {

            // for odd list length

            System.out.println("Inside if statememt");

            while (j - i >= 2) {

                int temp = list.get(i);
                list.set(i, list.get(j));
                list.set(j, temp);
                i = i + 1;
                j = j - 1;

            }
            System.out.println("List Size After Swap : " + list.size());

            System.out.println("Outside while in if statememt");

            System.out.println(matrix[0][0]);

        } else {

            // for even list length

            while (j - i >= 1) {

                int temp = list.get(i);
                list.set(i, list.get(j));
                list.set(j, temp);
                i = i + 1;
                j = j - 1;

            }

            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

                matrix[r][c] = list.get(c);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

When I replace the elements in the array in the last for loop, I get an Array Index Out of Bound Exception. Can anyone please guide me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local variable `matrix` that you initialize in `main` but the one you use in `swap` is the global one that is empty and of size [0][0].

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just starting out , didn't notice this. Thank you so much. Also I found a shorter approach,

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the array initialization is broke and one of a row of your matrix does not contain 3 elements, but you didn't post that part of the code. I have copied parts that you have posted plus initialization of the matrix field and this is working fine!

```
private static int columns = 3;
private static int rows = 3;
private static Integer[][] matrix = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> store = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            store.add(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("List Size Passed : " + store.size());

        swap(store, i);

    }

}
public static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> list, int r) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = list.size() - 1;

    System.out.println("List Size Received : " + list.size());

    if (list.size() % 2 == 1) {

        // for odd list length

        System.out.println("Inside if statememt");

        while (j - i >= 2) {

            int temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(j));
            list.set(j, temp);
            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;

        }
        System.out.println("List Size After Swap : " + list.size());

        System.out.println("Outside while in if statememt");


        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

            matrix[r][c] = list.get(c);

        }

    }
}
```

Please attach whole code including matrix initialization, but I am pretty sure that this is that problem.

Comment: Hi @Michal I've added the entire code. Can you tell me now what's the reason for that error. And thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified you matrix size as

```
static int[][] matrix=new int[3][3]; ?
```

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, I've added the entire code now. Can you please have a look and comment the reason for index out of bound exception

Comment: The global 2-D array is getting initialized with 0 x 0 size.  And you are using it the swap method.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
ArrayList<Integer> store = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    store.add(matrix[i][j]);
}
System.out.println("List Size Passed : " + store.size());

// swap(store, i);

Collections.reverse(store);
for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = store.get(j);
}

}
```

I reversed the list "store" and stored the result in the array when I called swap(...) This also eliminates the need to call swap(...)

Thanks for the support everyone.